# Corpus Juris Secundum request

Tags: legal-research

This is an unorthodox request for this medium, and may not even fit the kinds of questions allowed here, but... if anyone has access to Volume 50 of the Corpus Juris Secundum, I need the full text for § 275. It's in regards to some research I'm doing on voir dire, and I keep seeing this mentioned, and although CJS is available on Westlaw, it's not divided into volumes--apples and oranges.

Or, if someone can tell me how to translate 50 C.J.S. Juries § 275 into the CJS that's available on Westlaw, that would be great also. I've done a search on Westlaw in their version of the CJS for "voir dire" and found a number of sections that may equate to volume 50 § 275, but I need a bullseye.

If anyone can help, great! If not, I'll keep searching. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the law.

Comment: "What does this legal treatise say about the law relating to courtroom trials?" "Sorry, that's not a question about the law."

Comment: I would consider it a valid question. It is about the law and legal research is one of the topics within the scope of the forum.

Comment: This is clearly "about the law". The scope of LSE is not just "what is the statute or case law".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the input here, my own research, and opening a ticket with Westlaw and having them do some research for me, I have concluded that the language I am looking for exists only in Volume 50 of the C.J.S. from 1947 which is only available in hard copy, and, there is no cross-reference from older editions of the C.J.S. to the latest edition on Westlaw, because the organization of topics and text have evolved over time.

Comment: I've got a lead. Check back on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

Once you're in CJS, scroll down to "Juries." From there, it's just a matter of expanding the subgroups to see what sections they include.

In your case, its:

> *Corpus Juris Secundum*
>
> > Juries
> >
> > > IX. Constitution and Selection of Jury in General
> > >
> > > > B. Cognizable Groups
> > > >
> > > > > [§ 275. Age as cognizable group for fair cross-section](https://www.westlaw.com/Document/Id1d530c3b67c11d9a49dec8cdbddd959/View/FullText.html?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&VR=3.0&RS=cblt1.0)
> > > > >
> > > > > **Cognizable groups for jury selection purposes generally do not include age groups, such as young adults.**
> > > > >
> > > > > Cognizable groups for jury selection purposes generally do not include age groups, such as young adults, young people, or the young, or the elderly.
> > > > >
> > > > > It has also been held that young persons can constitute a cognizable group, but that their claimed underrepresentation does not invoke a high standard of judicial review. Moreover, there is authority that whether an age group is a cognizable group, for purposes of a challenge to the array of grand and traverse juries, depends on the time and location of the trial.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that's the updated version, and not what I'm looking for. I found that, too, on Westlaw. What I'm looking for (I've now been told) is not available on Westlaw, so it's probably only in some hard copy of a book some where. It includes this language "The examination of a juror on voir dire constitutes the taking of testimony on the issues raised as to his qualifications to serve in the case before the court" And possibly this, "The determination must be left largely to the sound discretion of the trial court.".

Comment: I see. Sections 475 and 481 seem to be the closest to what you're looking for in the current version.

Comment: Yes, those two sections seem to be the modern evolution of the single section from the 1947 edition cited in the case I am reviewing. Thank you for that. However, because I am limited to only that source material in the single case being reviewed, the modern edition is out of bounds.